# WPF Binding StringFormat Short Date String

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I would like to use Short Date named string format in WPF.

I tried something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='Short Date'}" />
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyPath, StringFormat=d}" />
```

which is culture sensitive and requires .NET 3.5 SP1 or above.

NOTE: This is case sensitive. "d" is the [short date format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#ShortDate) while "D" is the [long date format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#LongDate).

There's a full list of string format on the [MSDN page on Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and a fuller explanation of all the options on [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/07/07/customize-format-of-datetime-string-in-wpf-and-winform-data-binding.aspx)

However, there is one gotcha with this - it always outputs the date in US format unless you set the culture to the correct value yourself.

> If you do not set this property, the binding engine uses the **Language** property of the binding target object. In XAML this defaults to "en-US" or inherits the value from the root element (or any element) of the page, if one has been explicitly set.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

One way to do this is in the code behind (assuming you've set the culture of the thread to the correct value):

```
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

The other way is to set the converter culture in the binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyPath, StringFormat=d, ConverterCulture=en-GB}" />
```

Though this doesn't allow you to localise the output.

Comment: does this always output US format regardless of culture settings?

Comment: @CRice - yes it does - for some reason - you have set the culture yourself.

Comment: Thanks, pretty bad when the UI "d" outputs different to the xaml.cs "d" of the same date object.

Comment: ref the WPF culture bug, I just add             this.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag); after initializecomponent in every window;

Comment: I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74551502/6803297) that implements a simple `CultureAwareBinding` to help with this issue.

Answer (score 68):

Or use this for an English (or mix it up for custom) format:

```
StringFormat='{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'
```

Comment: You can also use 'ConverterCulture=' in your binding - which requires a value to indicate the format. (ConverterCulture='en-GB' is Great Britain).

Answer (score 33):

Use the `StringFormat` property (or `ContentStringFormat` on `ContentControl` and its derivatives, e.g. `Label`).

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:d}}" />
```

Note the `{}` prior to the standard `String.Format` positional argument notation allows the braces to be escaped in the markup extension language.

Comment: The `{}` will allow you to use `StringFormat='{}Created Date:{0:d}'` which otherwise would produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 22):

Some DateTime StringFormat samples I found useful. Lifted from [C# Examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone
```

Answer (score 16):

Be aware of the single quotes for the string format.
This doesn't work:

```
    Content="{Binding PlannedDateTime, StringFormat={}{0:yy.MM.dd HH:mm}}"
```

while this does:

```
    Content="{Binding PlannedDateTime, StringFormat='{}{0:yy.MM.dd HH:mm}'}"
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want add a string with the value use this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat= 'Date : {0:d}'}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5046460/6803297), I implement my own simple `CultureAwareBinding` in this way:

```
public class CultureAwareBinding : Binding
{
    public CultureAwareBinding()
    {
        ConverterCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    }
}
```

And use it in this way in XAML:

```
<TextBlock 
    Text="{viewHelpers:CultureAwareBinding Path=ActivationDate, StringFormat=d}"/>
```

Assuming that the `CultureAwareBinding` resides in the `viewHelpers` xmlns.

This way, I ensure that the `StringFormat=d` is using the correct `CultureInfo` of the system.