# WPF Date String Format in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to format string after a date has been selected by the DatePicker. The Format that I am getting is "9/5/2013 12:00:00 AM" and what I am trying to get is "9/5/2013". Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with the string format?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Start">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Start, StringFormat=d}" FontFamily="Verdana" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Start}" FontFamily="Verdana"  >
                <DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Calendar">
                          <Setter Property="DisplayMode" Value="Month"/>
                    </Style>
                </DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
            </DatePicker>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: i tried it getting value fine...can you share your complete datagrid xaml?

Comment: just add the whole dg

Comment: <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Start"> is the one with the string format in it

Comment: Please try answers in here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046429/wpf-binding-stringformat-short-date-string

Comment: i tried your code and it is working fine at my end... what are doing in cell mousedown event handler?

Comment: i just removed the mousedown event and it is still showing me '9/5/2013 12:00:00 AM'

Comment: is there a way that i can do this with a Converter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Start, StringFormat=d}" />
```

This requires .NET 3.5 SP1 or above.

Btw.: StringFormat is case sensitive. "d" is the [short date format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#ShortDate) while "D" is the [long date format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#LongDate).

Comment: stiil getting '9/5/2013 12:00:00 AM'

Comment: Hmm it does work for me, but your StringFormat works also. So your error may be somewhere else. Your DataGrid might generate the Column by itself. Try setting `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`.

Comment: Answer duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046429/wpf-binding-stringformat-short-date-string