# WPF Converter not working

Tags: wpf

I have an XML FILE that I will like to bind to a WPF datagrid , I have successfully done that as below

The issue I have is that the date is not in the format I would like and is coming up as 1966/12/15  and i want this to be in 15/12/1966

I wrote a converter for this (Below)

Imports System.Windows.Data

Public Class DateTimeConverter
    Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter

```
Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object,
                        ByVal targetType As System.Type,
                        ByVal parameter As Object,
                        ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) _
         As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert

    Dim DateValue As DateTime = CType(value, DateTime)

    Return DateValue.ToShortDateString

End Function

Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object,
                            ByVal targetType As System.Type,
                            ByVal parameter As Object,
                            ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) _
        As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack

    Dim strValue As String = value
    Dim resultDateTime As DateTime
    If DateTime.TryParse(strValue, resultDateTime) Then
        Return resultDateTime
    End If
    Return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue

End Function
```

End Class

and then tried using this in the XAML as below

```
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

But it throws an error saying it does not support converting from string .

can someone plese let me know what am doing wrong here .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662870/date-converter-using-wpf)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" />
```