# how to format a date inside a collection of objects using linq in c#

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a list of objects in my collection and need to format the date on an object date property (NoteDate) to show dates in the format like `"dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH:mm:ss"` whereas in database the format of the date is like `'2015-02-19 00:00:00.000'`. Below is my object

```
 public class Note
 {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string NoteText { get; set; }
 public DateTime? NoteDate { get; set; }
 }
```

and I populate the collection as below

```
var notesList=  _uow.Find<Note>(n => n.FK == leadId).ToList();
```

how can we write the query to get the desired date format?
thanks

Comment: you can change format at the time of displaying simply

Comment: A `DateTime` is a value (a date), not a string (a representation of the value). If you want a string, you need a string.

Comment: how do you present the dates? what does linq have to do with this?

Comment: Formatting at the front end is very obvious solution but the problem I' m having is I need to pass this list as a serialized json string to a jquery plugin which is not good at  formatting at their end. So I'm trying to convert it to a format I need beforehand

Comment: Can you add details of how you convert it to json to your question? Do also state why the json parser would have issues parsing a `DateTime`. It seems this should be a common case of conversion.

Comment: In my controller I'm doing the conversion as                                           `var notes = _leadsService.GetCallBackNotesByLeadId(id);
            return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notes), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: add it to your question via the `edit` button. When you've done that it is Ok to also delete the comment. That keeps all of the important information in the question itself instead of users having to read the comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are, properly, storing the date in a `DateTime?` object.  `DateTime` is simply a *storage* mechanism.

What you are really interested in is how to *display* the `DateTime` in some UI.

So here's the steps your Date/Time is going to take:

1. Get returned as query content from the database
2. Get stored in the `DateTime` property
3. Be shown to the user

To format a value from a `DateTime` object there are several options - check out the methods on the [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

Your dates will be represented as a `DateTime` instance .. how .NET decides to represent dates.

When you're displaying them to your user/using them for display somewhere, you can simply format them at that point. For example:

```
var notesList = _uow.Find<Note>(n => n.FK == leadId).ToList();

var thirdNoteDateString = notesList[2].NoteDate.ToString("dd MM yyyy");
```

Or, perhaps in a Razor view (if this was an MVC application):

```
@foreach (var n in Model.Notes) {
    <p>@n.NoteDate.ToString("dd MM yyyy")</p>
}
```

Hopefully that shows the difference. How the date is presented is up to you when you decide to present it.

Answer (score 0):

you should not modify the content of your buisness object just for a Show purpose,
You should use a converter or a StringFormat like :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}}" />
```

see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662870/date-converter-using-wpf) for more info