# WPF DatePicker: Custom DisplayText

Tags: wpf, binding, datepicker

I should have a custom format for my `DatePicker` `DisplayDate`, but my problem is, that format can't be made with the standard custom format tags (like `y`, `yyyy`, `d` and so on).

Is there a way you can bind the `SelectedDate` to a `DateTime` property and the `DisplayText` to a string property?

Comment: Follow up this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662870/date-converter-using-wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use `StringFormat` for specific `DatePicker` date format (check this example: [Changing the string format of the WPF DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819832/changing-the-string-format-of-the-wpf-datepicker))

Here is a simple example (make sure ViewModel is proper DataContext for you xaml file)

### **Main Window**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var vm = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = (ViewModel) DataContext;
        var date = context.SelectedDate;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Selected Date is {0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz}", date));
    }
}
```

### **View Model**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
}
```

### **Xaml file**

```
 <DatePicker VerticalAlignment="Top"
                SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}" />
 <Button Content="Button"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Margin="10,74,0,0"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="75"
         Click="Button_Click" />
```

You can change the format of `DateTime` when you show the MessageBox (check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

### **UPDATE**

For (yy-day Of Year), you can use:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Selected Date is {0:yy-}{1}", date, date.DayOfYear));
```

Comment: Ah thanks, so with the standart control it is only possible with a additional control (like the button), not directly in the textbox from the datepicker. I think then i don't get around a UserControl.

Comment: You can apply some events on your DatePicker if you want. I don't get exactly what is your target. But, if you want more information, I am available to answer your questions:). [Also, you can make a custom `UserControl` but, you can use already DatePicker. If you want to show at runtime in DatePicker's textbox you can do a Converter which does that (formats your format)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use string format property to display date in a custom way

```
  Binding="{Binding CustomerParcelDropTime,StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss \}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. My problem is that there is no format for what i need. I need tho show the year in two digits (yy) but after that i need the day of year and for that is no format. 
My current solution is to write a UserControl with a ordanary TextBox and a Calendar Popup. I just hoped i can use a standart control.