# WPF DataGrid modify bound data

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid, datetime-format

for testing purposes i created a simple object-list. I display the data in a datagrid with this code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" 
          IsReadOnly="True" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="50,30,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Height="251" 
          Width="544" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Birthday}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This works great, but my birthday is a datatype **DateTime** so how can i modify this bound data? I just want to show the DateTime.toShortDateString() value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Binding StringFormat Short Date String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046429/wpf-binding-stringformat-short-date-string)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `StringFormat` in your binding.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" /> // 16.12.2016
```

**See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5046460/4610605).**