# WPF how to show only date in datagrid column?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a datagrid with a datetime column. It shows both date and time but I only want the date. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show the column in the XAML please, so we can understand the bindings, and what have you tried so far.

Comment: use string format https://stackoverflow.com/q/5046429/366064

Comment: It works, thanks Bizhan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the date `"{Binding MyDateProperty, StringFormat=d}"` where it specifies that the datetime value be expressed as a *date*.