# IValueConverter uses the wrong culture with DateTime

Tags: wpf, datetime, ivalueconverter

Hi the below code is used to convert the DateTime format to current thread culture format

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is DateTimeOffset?)
    {
      var dto = (DateTimeOffset?)value;
      return dto.Value.ToString("t", culture);
    }
    return null;
}
```

But the DateTimeFormat in culture parameter is not updating to the current system datetime format, instead it uses the fixed format like HH:mm tt for short time.

The workarond for this is to set the language from the current thread as below, which we have done in App.Xaml but still DateTimeFormat will have the default format.

// fixes culture-specific binding formatting. See this link: [WPF Binding StringFormat Short Date String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046429/wpf-binding-stringformat-short-date-string)

```
this.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
```

I have gone through some blogs on this and looks like its a bug in WPF. Some guys suggest not to rely on culture for DateTime as DateTimePicker should give a selected date formatted to the local thread culture. This works fine if we remove the culture parameter in ToString().

Please provide your suggestions or solution for this :)

Comment: please show us your xaml, and did you put a break point in the converter? what are the inputs outputs and expected outputs

Comment: Yes, I had put the breakpoint. The culture in the input parameter will have "en-US" culture and ShotTimeFormat will be "hh:mm tt" even though the format set in the system is "tt hh:mm", but if we see in the "System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture" it will reflect the proper datetime format.

Comment: Xaml is like this 
<DataGridTextColumn Header="LoadedTime" Binding="{Binding Path=LoadedTime, Converter={StaticResource TimeOfDayValueConverter}}"/>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to set the language also on the WPF controls

(also in App.xaml.cs)

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but its not working with this line of code and at control level the format is as per the system settings. Still unable to understand why "culture" parameter in convert method is not updating.