# Convert timestamp (long type) into date and time from XAML using StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding, string-formatting

I have a timestamp property which is a `long` type and I have bound it to a `ListView` column.
Using XAML I am trying to convert this timestamp (`long` type) into a date and time dependent on the current regional settings of the machine on which is running.

I would like to get someting like this:

`mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm` or `dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm` (24 hour format)

or

`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm` PM or `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` PM (12 hour format)

depending on the machine regional settings.

So I use `StringFormat`:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Id"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Timestamp, StringFormat='g'}"/>
```

But it seems it is not working. In the grid view cell it is shown as a `long` number.

Comment: Write your own IValueConverter to have full control over that.

Comment: I think this might answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046429/wpf-binding-stringformat-short-date-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `g` is the [general format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#general-format-specifier-g), which will display the `long` as number.

> The general ("G") format specifier converts a number to the more compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation, depending on the type of the number and whether a precision specifier is present.

The date formatting mechanism does not work directly with `long`. A `DateTime` is unambiguous for representing a date and time, but how do you interpret `long`, as seconds, as milliseconds, from where? See the documentation for [Standard date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

> A standard date and time format string uses a single character as the format specifier to define the text representation of a `DateTime` or a `DateTimeOffset` value.

The obvious solution is to expose the dates through a property of type `DateTime`, not `long`. Then you can use the standard and custom date format specifiers in XAML `StringFormat`.

```
public DateTime Timestamp { get; }
```

Alternatively, you can create a custom value converter that converts the `long` to a `DateTime`.

```
public class LongToDateConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (!(value is long milliseconds))
         return value;

      var dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
      return dateTime.AddMilliseconds(milliseconds).ToLocalTime();

      // Alternative in > .NET Core 2.1
      //return DateTime.UnixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(milliseconds);
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Create an instance of the converter in any resources in scope, e.g. `Window.Resources`.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:LongToDateConverter x:Key="LongToDateConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Since the [conversion happens before formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Data.BindingBase.StringFormat)%3Bk(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks), you can keep the `StringFormat`.

> If you set the `Converter` and `StringFormat` properties, the converter is applied to the data value first, and then the `StringFormat`is applied.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Id"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Timestamp, Converter={StaticResource LongToDateConverter}, StringFormat='g'}"/>
```

You can refer to [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) to create the desired format string.

```
StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'
StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'

StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm'
StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'
```

---

Update for your comment:

> I forgot to say in my post (sorry) that this long timestamp was obtained by doing `DateTime.UtcNow.ToFileTimeUtc()` [...]

I assumed the Unix timestamp. As you can see, a `long` is pretty ambiguous. In this case you can convert the `long` back as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc?view=net-6.0).

> The `ToFileTimeUtc()` method is sometimes used to convert a local time to UTC, and subsequently to restore it by calling the `FromFileTimeUtc(Int64)` method followed by the ToLocalTime() method. **However, if the original time represents an invalid time in the local time zone, the two local time values will not be equal.**

The converter method would do exactly this.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   if (!(value is long milliseconds))
      return value;

   return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(milliseconds).ToLocalTime();
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say in my post (sorry) that this long timestamp was obtained by doing DateTime.UtcNow.ToFileTimeUtc() so it is the number of 100-nanoseconds intervals that has elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.)  as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc?view=net-6.0     so how can I modify your converter because you take into account from january 1970 and the conversion will not be correct in my case. Thx.

Comment: @Rodri Updated the answer and corrected the string formats.

Comment: Thanks, it worked as expected.

Comment: @Rodri I did not downvote. However, a tip to improve your question would be to include more information regarding the code you mentioned in your question. As you saw, it was quite unclear what the `long` data type really expressed, which makes it harder to answer without taking any assumptions like it being a UNIX timestamp. In other words the example is not a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).